# How to clear texbox after submission

Tags: asp.net, forms

Hi i wanted to know if there is any way that i can reset my form after the data has been added successfully into the database? Like after showing some message to the client the textbox should automatically clear out. 
What should I write in this block:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DeepSkyBlue;
            Label2.Text = "Master added successfully";
        }

        else
        {

            Label2.Text = "Master not added";

        }
```

Comment: You have to do it manually. Set the `TextBox.Text="";`

Comment: Is it a good practice to do it like this??

Comment: Yes. In webforms normally you will do this (or TextBox.Text = String.Empty;). Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2 ways :**

- You can do it in server side :

`TextBox.Text=string.Empty;` (at `PageLoad` or `PreRender`). ( I'd choose Prerender cuz your form might use the old value...)

- You can do it using javascript/jQuery :

`$(function (){$("form")[0].reset()});`

or `this.form.reset()`